# presentPopover - EXC_BAD_ACCESS; using Zombie Objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, exc-bad-access

I'm trying to get `presentPopoverFromRect` to work but I keep getting a crash due to bad memory access. `(EXC_BAD_ACCESS)`.

Here's the code, The last line is where it crashes:

```
- (void)showChat:(id)sender {

chat = [[PopupChatController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

chat.chatDelegate = self;

self.chatPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:chat];

CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(50, 0, 225, 25) ;

[self.chatPopover presentPopoverFromRect:myRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

}
```

Using gdb I've examined the retain counts for `self.view` and `self.chatPopover`:

EG.

```
p (int)[self.view retainCount]
```

and they are both fine ( > 0). So I am totally bemused as to what's going on here?

If anyone could help I would be very grateful for that.

Also, as an aside, I enabled Zombie Objects in XCode (*Product > Edit scheme > Diagnostics > Enable Zombie Objects*), but I'm not getting any output on any zombie variables in the console. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place?

Any advice on that would be appreciated also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: with or without arc? ... and when is the crash happening? how are chatDelegate and chatPopover declared? (strong,weak...)

Comment: Do you have a breakpoint set on Objective-C exceptions?  If not, try it...it might give a better error message than "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

Comment: With arc. The function is called on pressing a UIButton. chatDelegate is (nonatomic, retain) and chatPopover is (nonatomic, retain)... I'm not sure if that answers the question?

Comment: @PhillipMills Thanks for the help there. I did add a breakpoint and it enabled me to track down the error, which was actually in the window itself, not with the code I posted here. Frustrating!!!!! Thanks for your help though.

Comment: retainCount can never return zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a memory leak here for the variable **chat**.

Try the following code and make chat as a local variable.

```
- (void)showChat:(id)sender {

  PopupChatController *chat = [[PopupChatController alloc]    initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

  chat.chatDelegate = self;

  self.chatPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:chat];

  [chat release]; //since it's retained in the UIPopoverController

  CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(50, 0, 225, 25) ;

  [self.chatPopover presentPopoverFromRect:myRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

By the way, did you define the property chatPopover as retain?